# Arrays and JOptionPaneOption

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

I cant find a way to convert this to int.

here's the code

```
int array[] = new int [newsize];

    for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
        array[a] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"].");
    }
```

how to convert this into int..(sorry bad question)

```
array[a] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"].");
```

## thank you for helping for parsing first the inputted string to int

now ihave new problem. how can display ZERO, POSITIVE, NEGATIVE string with corresponding array in one JOptionPnae message..

heres my whole new code....

String display="";
        int z = 0;

```
    String size = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Prefered Size Of Your Array");
    int newsize = Integer.parseInt(size);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Entered "+newsize+".");

    int array[] = new int [newsize];

    for (int a=0; a<array.length;a++)
    {
        array[a] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"]."));

    }



    for (int a=0;a<array.length;a++)
    {
        display=display+array[a]+"\n";

        if (z == array[a])
        {
          String c=array[a]+"  ZERO";
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Arrays\n"+display+c);
        }
        else if (z < array[a])
        {
            String c =array[a]+"  POSITIVE";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Arrays\n"+display+c);
        }
        else if (z != array[a])
        {
            String c =array[a]+"  NEGATIVE";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Arrays\n"+display+c);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Arrays\n"+display+c);
     }
```

hope you get my question..

Comment: I suggest you create another question for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array[a] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"]."));
```

You should also do a check that the input value is an int, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter Value For Array["+a+"]." ))
```

Comment: This can breaks in `java.lang.NumberFormatException` and `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes, it can easily break. But then answers should be, IMHO, as straightforward as possible to follow. Defensive coding should be up to the actual implementation done by the author or whoever chooses to use the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 0):

do like below

```
 for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"].");
    if(value!=null){
          array[a] =  Integer.parseInt(value);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ah! The default value in `null` input is `0` in that index. But this breaks in `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the following code:

```
String length = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many number do you want to put into a array?");

    //Declare a string array with the length entered.
    String[] array = new String[Integer.valueOf(length)];

    /*
     * Input numbers for array
     */
    for(int i =0 ; i<array.length; i++)
    {
         array[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+i+"].");
    }

    /*
     *  Show Array information
     */

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Array elements are : "+ Arrays.toString(array));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check input text:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
for (int a = 0; a < array.length; ) {
    String inputText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array[" + (a + 1) + "].");
    if (inputText == null) { // Cancel button pressed 
        break;
    }
    try {
        array[a] = Integer.valueOf(inputText);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputText + " is not a number. Try again!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        continue;
    }
    a++;
}
```